# CSS Center crop image under min width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement a page banner that is full-width/height over a certain breakpoint, and below that breakpoint begins shrinking in width to retain its height. I have achieved this somewhat using the `min-width` rule, however below the breakpoint it crops only from the right side of the image. Since I usually have overlaid text that is either centered or left justified, the focal point of the image is usually in the center / right side. Are there any css rules I'm not aware of that define where the crop occurs below the min width, rather than it always taking off the right side? Thanks

Edit- here's some sample code

```
<div class="banner-container full-width ">
  <img class="background-image" src="/some-image.png">
  <div class="banner-text full">some text</div>
</div>
```

Here is the relevant css

```
.banner-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 275px;
}
.background-image {
  min-width: 755px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

I'm using an img element instead of setting the image as the background of the banner container because I want the container to take the height of the image. If I can do that using a background image instead that is probably the way to go

Comment: You should provide more information / a picture of your result would be so great too.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez this doesn't seem to be having any effect

Answer (score 0):

Use the '.banner-container' only to control the width of the image container. Then use the following for the image itself:

```
.banner-container {
  width: 50%
}
.background-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
.banner-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 275px;
  position: relative;
}
.background-image {
  min-width: 755px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

This will center the image horizontally by first moving it to the right by half of the container (using `left: 50%;` and then moving it back to the left by half of its own width (`transform: translateX(-50%);`).

To also center it vertically, you can also add `top: 50%` and instead of `translateX(-50%)` use `translate(-50%, -50%)`

Comment: This is very close, however it stretches the image out horizontally as it's taking the min-height, not the height of the image when it's over the min width